# Weblogic does not support EJB3?

Tags: client, weblogic, ejb-3.0

I use WebLogic Server 10.3.5.0 and I experienced no problems using EJB 2.x on it, but I want to deploy EJB3 and it does not work. I'm new to java ee , but I read a lot of information, I didn't find the answer. What I try:
1. Create my simple Calculator application

```
package test;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import java.lang.annotation.*;


@Remote
public interface Calculator {


    public int add(int x, int y);
}


package test;


import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.Remote; 



@Stateless(name="CalculatorBean", mappedName="EJBCalculatorBean")
@Remote(Calculator.class)
public class CalculatorBean {

    public int add(int x, int y){
        return x + y;
    }

}
```

Here's my ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">


  <enterprise-beans>


    <session>
      <ejb-name>Calculator</ejb-name>
      <remote>test.Calculator</remote>
      <ejb-class>test.CalculatorBean</ejb-class>
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
      <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>

  <assembly-descriptor>


    <container-transaction>
        <method>
            <ejb-name>Calculator</ejb-name>
            <method-name>*</method-name>
        </method>
        <trans-attribute>NotSupported</trans-attribute>
    </container-transaction>
  </assembly-descriptor>

</ejb-jar>
```

and my `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE weblogic-ejb-jar PUBLIC
'-//BEA Systems, Inc.//DTD WebLogic 6.0.0 EJB//EN'
'http://www.bea.com/servers/wls600/dtd/weblogic-ejb-jar.dtd'>

<weblogic-ejb-jar>


    <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
        <ejb-name>Calculator</ejb-name>
        <jndi-name>EJBCalculatorBean</jndi-name>
    </weblogic-enterprise-bean>



</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

I also have a very simple application.xml. I packed it into an exploded EAR folder, then I installed it from the weblogic console. When I tried to "activate changes" it failed with the message that the server is missing the home interface.

1. As far as I know EJB3 does not require home interface.
2. In EJB3 I don't have to specify any ejb information into my descriptors. Annotation have to provide the information for the server.

Am I right? And what can be the problem?

I also tried to use appc tool but it also missed the home interface.

Thx in advance!

I cleaned up all EJB entries from my `ejb-jar.xml` and `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml` and finnaly it worked. The problem is that I cannot access my bean from client running on different JVM. 
Here's my client code:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import test.Calculator;

public class Test {

    ;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        {
            try

            {
            Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"myuser");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mypassword");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://myweblogic:7001");
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);

            System.out.println("Initial Context created");

            Calculator calculator  = (Calculator)ctx.lookup("EJBCalculatorBean#test.Calculator");

            System.out.println("lookup successful");
            System.out.println("Calling EJB method . . .");
            System.out.println(calculator.add(3, 6));
            System.out.println("Output will be in Managed server console");
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
    }
}
```

A have the `wlclient.jar;javax.ejb.jar;calculator.jar` on my classpath. `calculator.jar` is the one I deployed to the server(it contains the `Calculator.class` and the`CalculatorBean.class`)
This client works fine when I run in the same JVM the weblogic uses, but in different JVM this error comes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
        ... 24 more
javax.naming.NamingException: Unhandled exception in lookup [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 257 completed: Maybe]
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.Utils.wrapNamingException(Utils.java:83)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:291)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:227)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at Test.main(Test.java:37)
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `CalculatorBean` implement `Calculator`

Comment: Thx Nayan, it was part of the solution.

Comment: @Mike82: When you say you "cleaned up all EJB entries" from ejb-jar.xml and weblogic-ejb-jar.xml, what exactly do you mean? Did you remove the bean declarations? Please give more detail – I am experiencing a similiar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Weblogic 10.3.5 does support EJB3.

Did you try to call your `SimpleCalculator` bean from the Test window in the `Console`? This way you can verify that it works correctly.

W.r.t. deployment, just place the `.ear` file into the `DOMAIN_HOMES/applications/my_domain/` folder and it will get deployed automatically, you do not have to go through the Console deployment every time.

After you test the `SimpleCalculator` bean in the console, you can then try the lookup, does it work this time?